# ReCaptcha response error with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've added a Google ReCaptcha on my website, this is the HTML form as provided by Google:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=my_public_key">
</script>

<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=my_public_key"
height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

And this is my jQuery (note that all the values sent by POST are correct, I've checked them all)

```
$('#captcha_form_btn').live('click', function () {
    var challenge = $('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val();
    var response = $('#recaptcha_response_field').val();
    var remoteip = $('#remoteip').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify',
        data:'challenge=' + challenge + '&response=' + response + '&remoteip=' + remoteip + '&privatekey=my_private_key',
        type:'post',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I am using AJAX to verify the client answer to the ReCaptcha, I send client's ip, response, challenge and my private key to get the response from the google API.

However, There's something wrong with API response being received, (I don't exactly know whether is received or not), the firebug javascript console displays a javascript error stating :

```
ReferenceError: incorrect is not defined

incorrect-captcha-sol
```

In a google API js file, and when I click on "incorrect-captcha-sol" ... it redirects me to a javascript file with these two lines :

```
false
incorrect-captcha-sol
```

I think, this is the response which is supposed to be sent back to the client, as json data, but here, I see that it's involved in a JS error in the API js file.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: you can't post with jsonp datatype. Therefore, your params are actually being sent as GET params, and then javascript is trying to execute `false; incorrect-captcha-sol` and `incorrect`, `captcha`, and `sol` are all undefined.

Comment: so what's the alternative then?

Comment: the alternative is.... this request is supposed to be made by your server, not the client.. unless of course it supports CORS.

Comment: sorry, But how can I make a request by the server?

Comment: using... whatever server-side language you use. for example, php.

Comment: I didn't done this before, all I know is client --> request --> server

Comment: okey, I got it now, thank you so much my friend... I'm going to check it out.

Comment: Yes, the client, would send a request to your server. your server would then act as a client and send a request to the google api(which is a server). the google api then returns data to your server, your server then returns that data to the browser. your private api key shouldn't be sent from teh browser anyway, otherwise it wouldn't be very private.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, it makes sense ^_^.. I'm starting to apply this solution.

Comment: Also, if you ever have anything that's a "private key" visible by anyone by checking your site's HTML, you're almost certainly doing something wrong :)

Comment: Yes, I've got this question when I saw it in My HTML source code, But @KevinB's answer solved this problem as well ... when PHP is the one who deals with the Private key, there's no more problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you'll want to use your server as a proxy to make this request so that:

1. your private key is kept private
2. you can bypass the same-origin policy

The process will be

`Browser -> Your Server -> Google Server -> Your Server -> Browser`

Comment: That's right, and I think curl will be good choice for this type of requests.